# Flutter build fails after invalidating cache using Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I have been able to build my Flutter app from vscode until I opened up the `android` directory with Android Studio and ran `Invalidate Caches`.

Now, whenever I build the app from vscode, I get the error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_background_service_android:compileDebugAidl'.
> Multiple build operations failed.
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/62637c64f877c8af42ac8dc6ce8fbbf7/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/cab7ec8a82ceb1f61e17432561f4c959/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c6279fa83105bc11a5de34cd2e89d35d/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/78dd2cd89330619bbf80dc30adcf2d21/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c233d8b521d7ea215c64cfc2b8881ecc/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7ae05e203e9d972a62634a71f086ccff/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4f57824c9fbc1fecb156fd16c1c01bc5/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d09289556508017faf8e3b7638912027/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d952825cbb9ff8e115bf20c08ed5401f/results.bin
      java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/23655fda6023d10ff9356a49cfbf247d/results.bin
      ...and 16 more failures.
...and:16
   > java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/62637c64f877c8af42ac8dc6ce8fbbf7/results.bin
```

Tried running

```
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

but it did not solve the errors.

From Anrdroid Studio, I tried running `Sync Project with Gradle Files` but it failed with the error

```
No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists. at:
com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.AndroidModule.prepare(GradleModules.kt:266)
```

`gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

What should I do?